# In vba what is the correct syntax for looping through multiple ranges using &

Tags: vba

I want to loop through code to do the following:  If there is an empty cell in column E, I want to highlight the entire row from A to H.  I've tried replacing the number with a variable using '&' as in below, but failed.  What is the syntax to do this using VBA?

```
 Sub CheckForBlanksInName()

    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = Sheet1.Range("A2:H103")
    Dim rowrng As Range

    'clear all color
    myRange.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

    'Last Row
    last_row = Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row 'Last row of the data set
    MsgBox last_row '=> returns
    For 

   rownum = 2 To last_row - 1
   If IsEmpty(Range("E" & rownum)) = True Then
        'myRange(("A & rownum : H" & rownum)).Interior.Color = RGB(166, 166,
      166) 'Gray DID NOT WORK

     ' Set rowrng = Range("A & rownum : H" & rownum)
        rowrng.Interior.Color = RGB(166, 166, 166)  'DID NOT WORK

     'Cell E is blank
          MsgBox rownum & "Cell E", rownum
   End If
   Next rownum
   End Sub
```

Comment: Are the two line breaks between `For` and `rownum` part of the code you're running? If so, try removing them. Also, there's no need to compare the result of `IsEmpty(Range("E" & rownum))` to `True`.

Comment: try `("A" & rownum , "H" & rownum)`

Answer (score 0):

You have several syntax errors on your code. You could do the following:

```
Sub CheckForBlanksInName()
        Dim myRange As Range
        Set myRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:H103") '<~~ use sheet name instead
        myRange.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone            '<~~ clear color
    '------
        Dim last_row As Long                            '<~~ declare last_row
        last_row = Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row          '<~~ fix last_row
    '------
        For rownum = 2 To last_row - 1
            If IsEmpty(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & rownum)) = True Then '<~~ use complete addresses
                Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & rownum & ":H" & rownum).Interior.Color = RGB(166, 166, 166) '<~~ use complete addresses
            End If
        Next rownum
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

or just loop through the rows

```
Sub CheckForBlanksInName2()

   Dim rng As Range, roww As Range
   Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A2:H103")
       rng.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

   For Each roww In rng.Rows
       If IsEmpty(roww.Cells(1, 5)) Then roww.Interior.ColorIndex = 50
   Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply loop through specific `Cells` in the "E" `Column`  and depending on the result of their `isEmpty()` function result, you can highlight them as you like.

```
Dim cell As Range
Dim ws as Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1") ' <- change to whatever sheet you're using
Dim lr as Long: lr = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For Each cell In ws.Range("E1:E" & lr)
    If IsEmpty(cell) Then
        cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 27
    End If
Next cell
```

Produces the expected result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1.) Loop Syntax: For...To should be on the same line.

2.) Range Syntax: Your attempt to use "myRange(("A & rownum : H" & rownum))" is 
    referring to a range within the "myrange" range object. This can be done but 
    you don't need it here and this is not the proper syntax. Refer To: 
    http://www.cpearson.com/excel/cells.htm

Here's a few ways to refer to the range you want to highlight:

sheet1.Range("A" & rownum & ":H" & rownum)

sheet1.Range("A" & rownum.row & ":H" & rownum.row)

sheet1.Range("A" & rownum, sheet1.range("A" & rownum).offset(0,7))

sheet1.Range(sheet1.Cells(rownum, "A"), sheet1.Cells(rownum, "H"))

sheet1.Range(sheet1.Range("A" & rownum), sheet1.Cells(rownum, "H"))

VBA allows a lot of variation when referring to ranges but a few tips:
    1. Fully qualify your sheet reference [e.g. - sheet1.Range(sheet1...)] 
    2. Be careful with the tedious quotations
    3. Use With...End With blocks

3.) Your last_row variable will be unreliable when there are blank cells in your 
    data because it will return the last row before any blank cell. See below

4.) You don't need a loop to accomplish this; I suggest using autofilter instead.

Here's how I would do it:

```
   Sub CheckForBlanksInName()
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim last_row As Double

    With Sheet1

      last_row = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'Last row of the data set
      MsgBox last_row '=> returns
      Set myRange = .Range("A2:H" & last_row)

      'clear all color
      myRange.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

      .AutoFilterMode = False  'clear any filters
      .Range("E1:E" & last_row) _ 
        .AutoFilter _
            field:=1 _
          , Criteria1:="=" _
          , Operator:=xlFilterValues  'filter column "E" on blank cells

      'Highlight
      myRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Interior.Color = vbYellow

      .AutoFilterMode = False  'clear filters

    End With
   End Sub
```